# complex pivot in Python

Tags: python

I have a large set of data.
What I did in Python is:
I apply the filter first
Then create a pivot

However when I check the result, it seems like Python did not perform the data filters. Python only did the pivot table.

Please advise

```
bonds[(bonds['Checkpoint'] == 1) 
      & (bonds['Volcker Desk'] != "FX CASH")
     & (bonds['Volcker Desk'] != "NMRC")]

bonds=pd.pivot_table(
    bonds,
    index=['rating'],
    columns=['Bond Type'],
    values=['Holding Amt 1'],
    aggfunc='sum'
)

bonds
```

Comment: python performed the filter but you never save the filtered dataframe to a variable: `filtered_bonds = bonds[(bonds['Checkpoint'] == 1) & (bonds['Volcker Desk'] != "FX CASH") & (bonds['Volcker Desk'] != "NMRC")].copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering the data and not using/assigning it to another variable

```
bonds_filtered = bonds[(bonds['Checkpoint'] == 1) 
    & (bonds['Volcker Desk'] != "FX CASH")
    & (bonds['Volcker Desk'] != "NMRC")]

bonds_pivot=pd.pivot_table(
    bonds_filtered ,
    index=['rating'],
    columns=['Bond Type'],
    values=['Holding Amt 1'],
    aggfunc='sum'
)
```

if you don't want to introduce new variables you can rename everything to bonds. Just don't forget to assign it